# How to autogenerate a Unique ID from Immutables Criteria Library?

Tags: java, mongodb, uniqueidentifier, auto-generate, immutables-library

The advice given on [Immutables site](https://immutables.github.io/mongo.html) is to switch to the new [Immutables-Criteria](https://immutables.github.io/criteria.html) functionality. In this sense I try to convert my project so that instead of [Immutables-MongoDB](https://immutables.github.io/mongo.html) it uses the [Immutables-Criteria](https://immutables.github.io/criteria.html) .

[Immutables-MongoDB](https://immutables.github.io/mongo.html) provides the `Id.generate()` method as a Default way to auto-generate unique id for an object. There is an [example here](https://immutables.github.io/mongo.html#id-attribute).

```
import org.immutables.value.Value;
import org.immutables.mongo.types.Id;

@Value.Immutable 
public abstract class ExampleMongoID{   

      // Autogenerating a id and converting it to a String
      // This is a slightly modified and simplifed version of the [example of the site][3].
      @Mongo.Id   
      @Value.Default   
      public String id() {
        return Id.generate().toString();   
     }

}
```

However the equivalent tag does not have any method similar or equivalent to the `generate()` method. Neither such a method related to ID could be found in the criteria API.

In the project that needs to be converted `Id.generate()` is used prior to inserting/coming. 
Is there any way I can achieve the effect of calling `Id.generate()` from the new [Immutables-Criteria](https://immutables.github.io/criteria.html) API?
I would prefer to know what is the preferred [Immutables-Criteria](https://immutables.github.io/criteria.html) based way. One solution could be to auto-generate a GUID but I would like to use the recommended approach (if there is one) so I can be more compatible with future updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question, I have been using this approach for quite some time and seems to work well.

```
@Value.Immutable 
public abstract class ExampleMongoID{   

  @Criteria.Id
  @Value.Default
  public String getId() {
     return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

}
```